# How to parse time without timezone conversation?

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm parsing a `xs:datetime` to joda `DateTime`, but would like to parse it without the timezone, and let the date+time remain unchanged.

How could I achieve this? The following subtracts the timezone instead, but that's not what I want.

```
ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().parseDateTime("2015-10-25T08:45:00.000+11:00"); //2015-10-24 23:45:00 WHY?
```

Comment: What do you mean 'subtracts the timezone'? That code looks correct for handling date-times. I notice that the time in the comment is 10 hours before the parsed time, not 11 - however it looks like [October 25 is when DST changes](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2015.html), which would explain that.

Comment: @AdamS If I only consider the input string then it is NOT correct to apply any DST-changes because an offset like +11:00 is just a fixed offset without any DST-Information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the right temporal type:

```
LocalDateTime ldt =
    ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().parseLocalDateTime("2015-10-25T08:45:00.000+11:00");
System.out.println(ldt); // 2015-10-25T08:45:00.000
```